# Stored procedure that creates #table - unable to find it in list of tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that creates a local table - #table1

The stored procedure is supposed to look for values and create the table and insert the values into it...

```
INSERT INTO #table1
```

I execute the stored procedure and it shows that 1 row() affected, however, I am unable to find this table in the list of my tables. Why am I not able to see it or access it?

EDIT: I'm running the stored procedure inside SQL Server against a database. At the end of the stored procedure, the last line is:

```
Select * from #table1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What list of tables? Where are you looking? It is in tempdb anyway and will be given a longer system generated name. It will also be dropped automatically when the proc exits assuming the proc creates it. This is the prefix for *temporary* tables.

Comment: @MartinSmith - the stored procedure runs agains a whole DB and looks for specific values in all tables all fields. When found, it's supposed to enter the value into #table1. I'm not sure if this tables is supposed to be in the same DB? i've never worked with #tables

Comment: If  you create a temporary table inside a procedure, it will be dropped automatically when the procedure execution ends (and you can't see it from other sessions when it's running)

Comment: @JamesZ - so what do I do in this choice? create a physical table and have the SP insert it there instead of #table1?

Comment: You can also use ##table. That will be visible (and contents shared) with all the sessions, but will be dropped once the original session ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #table is a local temp table. It does not exist as a permanent table that you can look for outside the scope of the stored proc. Once the stored proc is run, the temp table is dropped because it is no longer in scope. Temp tables are stored temporarily in the tempdb database but with a different name because two people running the stored procedure at the same time would each have a table that can be referenced in the proc as @table but it would be two separate tables in the tempdb.

Now if what you are doing is looking to see what is in #table at a point in the stored proc in order to troubleshoot the proc, then you need to set thing up in the proc so that you can see the results at different stages or when you hit a certain state such as an error.

This could be something like adding a @debug variable to the proc so that when you are in debug mode, you can select the results to the screen when you are running something like:

```
CREATE PROC test_proc (@Id INT, @debug BIT = 0)
AS

CREATE TABLE #temp(id INT)

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES (@Id), (1), (2)

IF @debug = 1 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM #temp
END

UPDATE #temp
SET Id = id-1

IF @debug = 1 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM #temp
END

GO
```

You would then execute the proc without debugging as so (note that since I am not returning something or inserting to permanent tables, this proc will insert to #temp but you can't see anything. I just didn't want to get complicated here, the steps of the proc will vary depending on what you want to do, the concept I am trying to show is how to use the debug variable):

```
EXEC test_proc @Id= 5
```

and with debugging as

```
EXEC test_proc @Id= 5, @debug= 1
```

Or it might involved using a table variable instead (because they don't get rolled back on error) and then inserting the data from that table variable into a logging table after the rollback occurs in the Catch block, so that you can see the values at the time the error occurred.

Without knowing more about why you are looking for #temp and what the data means and is used for, it is hard to say what you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried refreshing the tables after exceuting Stored procedure